# Topology, normal spaces

Tags: general-topology

Let X be a normal space, and U1 and U2 two open subsets such that X = U1 ∪ U2. Show that there are two closed subsets, A1 and A2, such that A1 ⊂ U1, A2 ⊂ U2 and A1 ∪A2 = X
I tried to use the following characterization
A topological space X is normal if and only if for each closed subset F ⊂ X and each neighborhood W of F, there is an open U in X such that F ⊂ U ⊂  Cl(U)⊂W

my only advance has been, to see that if two open covers then their complements are closed disjoint
If you have any advice or any other characterization that helps me I would appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

Let $C_i=U_i^{c}, i=1,2$. ($E^{c}$ denotes complement of $E$) Then $C_1$ and $C_2$ are disjoint closed sets and hence there exists disjoint open sets $U_1,U_2$ such that $C_i \subset U_i,i=1,2$. Take $A_i=U_1^{c}$ and $A_2=U_2^{c}$

Comment: Thanks for the answer, try it and everything works correctly just that I can not argue that A1UA2 = X

Comment: @KevinAlonso $U_1\cap U_2=\emptyset$. Taking complements on both sides we get $A_1\cup A_2=X$.